# Error in entering Docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I have deployed my code into some ec2 instance. On entering the instance I have few docker containers running. I am trying to enter into one such docker container but I am getting the following error:

OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Anybody faced this issue or know the resolution? Thanks in advance

Comment: What's image is your build based on? Try `sh` instead of bash.

Comment: Can you include the command you are using to "enter" the container? Have you checked if this kind of container actually has `bash`?

Comment: you can use docker exec -it contianer bash|ash if this still issue then share your docker file

Comment: EC2 or Elastic container service?

Comment: Its EC2. I realised its a scratch container, that's why may be I am not able to enter.